# How to create edges within nodes under the same parent node in Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm new to Gremlin. I want to connect nodes "child" under the same "parent" node with "sibling" edge.

Initial state:

- (:parent {name: 'A'})-[parent_of]->(:child {'name: 'A1'})
- (:parent {name: 'A'})-[parent_of]->(:child {'name: 'A2'})
- (:parent {name: 'B'})-[parent_of]->(:child {'name: 'B1'})
- (:parent {name: 'B'})-[parent_of]->(:child {'name: 'B2'})

Expected:

- Initial state +
- (:child {name: 'A1'})-[sibling]->(:child {'name: 'A2'})
- (:child {name: 'A2'})-[sibling]->(:child {'name: 'A1'})
- (:child {name: 'B1'})-[sibling]->(:child {'name: 'B2'})
- (:child {name: 'B2'})-[sibling]->(:child {'name: 'B1'})

Image expected:
[Expected Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQgeV.png)

How should I write a gremlin query for this?

Comment: You can do all of this in one query using a combination of `addV`, `addE` and `property` steps. I will add an answer in a little while that expands on that if helpful.

Comment: Do you want to create the initial state and then add the sibling relationships using a query or are you looking for one query to just create it all in one go?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence, I have the initial state already. I am interested in a query that creates "sibling" relationship.

Comment: Ok I will add an answer ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So given this graph

```java
g.addV('Parent').property('name','A').as('a').
  addV('Parent').property('name','B').as('b').
  addV('Child').property('name','A1').as('a1').
  addV('Child').property('name','A2').as('a2').
  addV('Child').property('name','B1').as('b1').
  addV('Child').property('name','B2').as('b2').
  addE('parent-of').from('a').to('a1').
  addE('parent-of').from('a').to('a2').
  addE('parent-of').from('b').to('b1').
  addE('parent-of').from('b').to('b2').iterate()
```

We can add the sibling relationships a few different ways. It really just depends on how you want to lookup the siblings. While I did not show it above, it is common in Gremlin to give each vertex a custom ID and use that to find vertices. In this example I will just look them up by name.

To find the children of each parent we can start out with a simple query such as:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Parent').out()
```

or we could use

```java
g.V().hasLabel('Child')
```

Given that we have found the children we just need to extend the query to connect the ones with a common parent. There are actually a lot of ways this query can be written (I will try to revisit this answer a little later to show some other ways and discuss possible optimizations). This should give you some basic building blocks.

```java
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('Parent').as('p').
......1>        out().as('c').
......2>        addE('sibling').
......3>          to(V().hasLabel('Child').where(neq('c')).where(__.in('parent-of').as('p'))   
......4> )

==>e[40][24-sibling->26]
==>e[41][26-sibling->24]
==>e[42][28-sibling->30]
==>e[43][30-sibling->28]
```

To verify it worked

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Child').out('sibling').path().by('name')

==>[A1,A2]
==>[A2,A1]
==>[B1,B2]
==>[B2,B1]
```

In a large graph such as a big family tree this could be an expensive query and targeting specific parents or children would obviously be a good optimization.

EDITED to add:

Here is an alternative way to achieve the same goal but starting from each child and traversing back to the parent and then out to the siblings while avoiding connecting to yourself.

```java
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('Child').as('c').
......1>       addE('sibling').
......2>         to(__.in('parent-of').out('parent-of').where(neq('c')))
     
==>e[84][68-sibling->70]
==>e[85][70-sibling->68]
==>e[86][72-sibling->74]
==>e[87][74-sibling->72]
```

Comment: I also added another example where the query starts from the children and not the parent. As I mentioned, there are many ways this could be written.

Comment: Thank you for this and I just realized that you are the author of Practical Gremlin which is the book I am reading to study Gremlin. Really appreciate your effort on writing the book! Coming from SQL background, I thought there should be a use of a `group`  and a `by` for my case. Your answer directs me to which part of the book I should focus more.